# New version of task definition in ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a ECS cluster running.I want to create a new version of task definition using awscli.

I know i need to use below command to create new version.

```
aws ecs register-task-definition  --family API-servie-fetch --cli-input-json file://TD-DC.json
```

But i am not getting from where to get this JSON file "file://TD-DC.json" ?
I belive i have to  update image tag and version number in this file but from where i can get this file ?

Note:- My task is already running and i only want to update it with new image rest all parameters should be same.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtained current task definition in json format using [describe-task-definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html). Once you have it, you can modify it as you want, and then upload as new version.

If you work in command line, you can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to modify/process the original task definition in json format.

Comment: I tried with JSON i fetched from command "aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition FETCH-API-TD:55" but i got error in register-task-definition.